# React Native ads (Adcolony) - Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, adcolony, react-native-bridge

I've used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ad-colony) npm library which is a react native bridge for adcolony ads SDK , i was supposed to display advertise in my application .

When i imported and used mentioned library in my react native application i got following error:

[image]

This is how i use the adcolony SDK in my react-native app:

```
  .
  .
  .

  line 6  : import RNAdColony from 'react-native-ad-colony';
  .
  .
  .

  line 187: RNAdColony.setUser("456456456456");
  line 188: RNAdColony.showAdReward("vz0533ae6a620249ef91");
```

**How can i solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently found the answer of my question :

The above error occurs because linking between SDK and React-native project was not established.

This error occurs because Adcolony.setUser() method was return an undefined and React-native didn't get what happened; eventually an unhandled promise error have been shown .

After a lot of searches, i was understand that when you using Expo to develop your React-native project , Expo needs Expokit which is a library that allows Expo to run React-native commands such as "react-native link" ; in other words,  Expokit is an extra library for custom SDK implementation.

[What is Expokit?](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/)